# Attaching metadata to Bugsnag with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bugsnag

Reading the documentation I found that I can append data to a threw Exception this way:

```
Bugsnag::setMetaData([
    'account' => [
        'paying' => true,
        'name' => 'Acme Co'
    ]
]);
```

I want to append the user email. Where should I place this code? I added it to Handler@render but the information is not being showed in the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

`render()` comes after `report()` in the exception flow, so if you're reporting to bugsnag in `report()` and setting metadata in `render()` it won't work:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cb48cf54fcd16a8cac246fcb98340cc2c9ed6b5a/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L80-L86

Your bugsnag code should all be going into `report()` since you're reporting the error to an external service.

In any case, it's hard to provide any further information without seeing what you're actually doing in your exception handler.

Comment: Excuse me for chatting you this way, but I was not able to find any contact of yours. Could you leave your email here please? I will remove this inappropriate comment afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To set customized user information, you can register a callback:

```
Bugsnag::registerCallback(function ($report) {
    $report->setUser([
        'id' => '123456',
        'name' => 'Leeroy Jenkins',
        'email' => 'leeeeroy@jenkins.com',
    ]);
});
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/#identifying-users).